# jQuery draggable and invoke function

Tags: jquery-ui-draggable

I have a table of games laid out in a grid and I want to drag any square to anther square, and invoke a function. The game squares must have an id corresponding to the game they represent (or contain a div with that ID).

I want to drag any table cell to any other table cell and invoke an ajax action with both id numbers, so I can swap the game bookings.

I don't know where to start and can't find anything close.

Comment: have you checked the jquery draggable? take a look here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: Yes, I have the how to, but that doesn't show me how to extract the id number from each element. Furthermore, I need to make the id of each box the id of the game being swapped. The examples i have seen relate to a known id being dragged to another known id and since this can be any td or div to any other td or div in the grid. A problem with the example is dragging from a single known div to another. I need to be able to drag from an arbitrarily named id to another and extract 2 id numbers as params for an ajax call.

Comment: perhaps a similar approach. Instead of id, read what you want from inside a rel attribute. Example: <div id="table_cell_2" rel="2">blah blah</div>
That way, you can guess the id name since it will be [table_cell_xxx], where the xxx you get from rel attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> > Yes, I have the how to, but that doesn't show me how to extract the id number from each element.

You should be able to get everything you need when the drop is performed.
If your basic set up is:

```
    <table><tr><td id="cell_1"></td><td id="cell_2"></td></tr></table>
```

Just set the cells as draggable AND droppable with this in your drop event:

```
    $('td').draggable().droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                    var dragged_id = ui.draggable.attr('id'); // cell that was dragged
                    var dropped_id = $(this).attr('id'); // cell dropped into
                    $.ajax(...);
            }
    });
```